# Installing RPM Dependencies

Tags: linux, installation, rpm

I am trying to install dbus-1.1.2-12.el5.i386 but I get the error

" dbus-libs = 1.1.2-12.el5 is needed by dbus-1.1.2-12.el5.i386" :-(

So I downloaded "dbus-libs-1.1.2-12.el5.i386.rpm" in the same directory and ran the 
command rpm -ivh  dbus-1.1.2-12.el5.i386 again, but I still got the same error. On searching on Forums I found that RPM takes care of dependecies if they are present in the same Directory. but it does not work with -ivh option ??

Answer (score 2):

Steve B is correct:

```
yum install dbus-libs
yum install dbus
```

yum will also allow you to do "whatprovides" for a package:

```
yum whatprovides dbus-libs
```

This will show you if you have another version of dbus-libs "installed" on your system, it spools out what repos provide the package and is any are provided (installed) locally.

Also helpful is:

```
rpm -q dbus
```

which will show any packages that are locally install as will:

```
rpm -q dbus-libs
```

or

```
rpm -qa | grep 'dbus'
```

You may find that you already have an eariler version of dbus installed, which case:

```
yum -y update dbus
```

Hope this helps.
http://www.of-networks.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dependant RPMs before installing dbus. You should also know that this is the hard way, these days RPM-based distributions usually have a dependancy managment system so that you don't need to do this by hand. e.g. on Redhat/Fedora/Centos you can just type "yum install mypackagename".